# How to use Github push and pull for live site and localhost config

Tags: git, github

I am still a bit confused how to use github the right way.
i have a master branch on github which is up to date with my live site on the server.
i have also made a branch dev-1 which is up to date with my local code.

on my local site the config files are configured with a callback URL of localhost, while on the live site the config uses the live URL of course.

but how do i now update my code which i test on localhost and want then to push it to the live site without alternating the config files?

i edit the .gitignore file to exclude the config folder, but it doesn't work or i made it wrong.

what is the recommended user flow?

Comment: Config files should not be under version control. Maybe you could be more specific what you mean by "it doesn't work". What doesn't work? Adding entries to `.gitignore` just makes them not show up when you do a `git status` and the like. If you already put them in version control, make copies of the config files/folders and then remove them from version control and put the copies back as your config on both your systems. Then, you can just push & pull all other files without affecting your configs. And you can add some push/pull hooks to automate updates to specific branches.

Comment: i think this is exactly what i need. i was thinking with putting the config files/folders in .gitignore will archive that. but they still show up on the github repo. So, how do i remove the files/folders from version control? Or, how do i exclude them in the first place (when i start a new github project) Note: I am using the meanio stack and his folder structure. so excluding the folder config/env is what i need. and keep them on both systems once configured just untouched. Is this right?

Comment: Exclude in the first place: Don't add them and put their paths in `.gitignore`. Remove them: By using the version control's remove function, e.g. `git rm`, but as I said, back up your configs (or everything) first, then delete them from version control, then add them again to your working directory (but not version control) and have them ignored. I think you should really read up on using git, e.g. [here](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2) or [here](http://gitref.org/).

Answer (score 0):

If you exclude the config folder, how are you going to use the configuration on production or locally? How will you be changing it for both roles? There probably will be different callback URLs, username/passwords for APIs etc. Also, it is not advisable anyways to add any sensitive information like username/passwords on git trees (even if the github account is private).

I think the best practice for this is having a one common configuration module which gets any different or sensitive setting parameter from the environment. And you would of course set this environment variables using bashrc or some other similar technique both on production servers and on your local dev server.

Comment: i want to configure the 2 different config files once with their correct settings specific for each system (localhost and server), and then keep them just out of sync when making pull, push and commits.

Comment: If it is two different files, one for production and other for testing for example, why do you not want them in the version control? It is sensitive information which you shouldn't add (like username/passwords) and these could be retrieved from env variables.

Comment: @tayfun Config files (except for config defaults) should not be in version control. Never.